# Check if an integral is convergent and calculate its value

Tags: definite-integrals

I have improper integral $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(x)}{(1-2\sin(x))^{1/3}} dx$$

I have to check if it is convergent. If yes, then i have to evaluate it.

I think it is convergent. I can make substitution $t=\sin(x)$. But what next?

Comment: It might be interesting to make a substitution $t=1-2\sin x$...

Comment: and then  employ fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Your substitution is also OK, but the one suggested by @abiessu may be simpler. You ask what next, what is the current integral you got?

Comment: The issue is the behaviour near $\pi/6$ (and $5\pi/6$, but that's similar).  To investigate, make the substitution suggested by abiessu.

Comment: @adm34 it is convergent.

Comment: The answer strongly depends on how you define the function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ for negative $x$.

Comment: isnt it $-1$   ? Im confused now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since it is an improper integral you need to split it into the sum of three parts

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow\frac{5\pi}6}\lim_{b\rightarrow\frac{\pi}6}\int_a^\pi \frac{\cos(x)}{(1-2\sin(x))^{1/3}} dx + \int_b^a\frac{\cos(x)}{(1-2\sin(x))^{1/3}} dx + \int_0^b\frac{\cos(x)}{(1-2\sin(x))^{1/3}} dx$$

If you make the substitution $t = 1-2\sin(x)$ you will get $dt = -2\cos(x) dx$.

The boundaries become $t(\pi) = 1-2\sin(\pi) = 1$, $t(\frac{5\pi}6) = 1-2\sin(\frac{5\pi}6) = 0$, $t(\frac{\pi}6) = 1-2\sin(\frac{\pi}6) = 0$, and $t(0) = 1-2\sin(0) = 1$

Use this to simplify your equation to $$\int_0^1\frac{-1}{2t^{1/3}} dt + \int_0^0\frac{-1}{2t^{1/3}} dt + \int_1^0\frac{-1}{2t^{1/3}} dt$$

We will use $$\int_0^0\frac{-1}{2t^{1/3}} dt = 0$$ and $\int_1^0\frac{-1}{2t^{1/3}} dt = -\int_0^1\frac{-1}{2t^{1/3}} dt$

So the sum totals to $0$

Comment: Can I use substiution first and then split integral?

Comment: I believe you can if the integral converges. That is the way I answered at first before deleting my answer and coming from this direction.

Comment: if the upper limit of the integral was pi/2 instead of pi then integral would be non zero right?

Comment: With the upper limit of $\frac\pi2$ you would simplify to $$\int_0^1\frac{-1}{2t^{1/3}} dt = -\frac34$$

Comment: Wolfram says it's $3/2$...

Comment: I plugged it into Wolfram like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28-1%2F%282*t%5E%281%2F3%29%29+t%3D0..1%29)

Comment: But the question is if we can do substitution like that to improepr integral?

Comment: the factor of $-\frac12$ comes from the substitution. in essence you have $dx = \frac{-1}{2\cos(x)} dt  $

Comment: That is the question. The short answer is yes, the long one is only if the integral converges. I split the integral into pieces, then used a substitution which left no singularities in the integrals. This led me to believe that the integral converges to $0$. If I had just done the substitution without checking convergence first, I would not be confident that the answer was correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, we can state
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx+\int_{y=\pi/2}^{y=0}\frac{\cos (\pi-y)}{[1-2\sin (\pi-y)]^{1/3}}d(\pi-y)\\
\end{align}
Where $y=\pi-x$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx-\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\frac{-\cos y}{(1-2\sin y)^{1/3}}dy\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx+\int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{\cos y}{(1-2\sin y)^{1/3}}dy\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}{(1-2\sin y)^{1/3}}dy\\
&=0
\end{align}
This is true if $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx$$ converges.

---

By using $t=\sin x,\;\;dt=\cos x dx$ we have
$$\int\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx=\int\frac{dt}{(1-2t)^{1/3}}=-\frac{3}{4}(1-2t)^{2/3}+C=-\frac{3}{4}(1-2\sin x)^{2/3}+C$$
Then
$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx=\lim_{b\to\frac{\pi}{6}^-}\int_0^{b}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx=\lim_{b\to\frac{\pi}{6}^-}-\frac{3}{4}(1-2\sin b)^{2/3}+\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{4},$$
$$\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx=\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}{6}^+}\int_a^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx=\frac{3}{4}+\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}{6}^+}\frac{3}{4}(1-2\sin a)^{2/3}=\frac{3}{4}$$
Then, the integral converges, also
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx=\frac{3}{2}$$
Therefore
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{(1-2\sin x)^{1/3}}dx=0$$